# PDO bindParam behaving strangely

Tags: php, pdo

I am having a problem getting PDO bindParam to work correctly.  Using this code:

```
$foo = "bar";

$stmt_1 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo = $foo");
$stmt_1->execute();
$results_1 = $stmt_1->fetchAll();

$stmt_2 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo = ?");
$stmt_2->bindParam(1, $foo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt_2->execute();
$results_2 = $stmt_2->fetchAll();

$stmt_3 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo = :foo");
$stmt_3->bindParam(":foo", $foo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt_3->execute();
$results_3 = $stmt_3->fetchAll();
```

$results_1 contains only the row(s) where foo = bar, $results_2 is empty, and $results_3 contains every entry in "table"

bindValue has the exact same problem, too.  Anyone know what's going on here or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Note: don't even bother with `bindParam`. Use `$stmt->execute(array($foo));`. :)

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the difference between cases 2 and 3. What is the database driver?

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem.  For some reason, the variables I was setting from $_POST weren't available to the internal functions of a class I had defined, so I added a parameter array to the class to hold the bound variables, and now everything works.

Comment: +1, maybe you could show some demonstrating code and accept your own answer?

Comment: I would, but this was so long ago that I don't have the code any more, and if I recall correctly, it was a custom class that caused the problem in the first place, so I doubt that it would be very useful to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

(I'll do a new answer because I misunderstood the question in the other one.)

By default PDO silently ignores errors and returns empty results. This could explain #2. For example, if your table is really called "table" and you didn't quote it with backticks (`table` is a reserved keyword). Turn on error reporting to see if this is the case (see below).

In #3, all rows might be returned because the condition is tautological: `foo = foo` or `:foo = :foo` or `'foo' = :foo`.

Here's a complete program that works correctly for me. If it doesn't work for you, it's likely a bug in a particular version of PHP, PDO or MySQL.

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'user', 'password');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$foo = 'bar';

$stmt_1 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE foo = '$foo'");
$stmt_1->execute();
$results_1 = $stmt_1->fetchAll();

$stmt_2 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE foo = ?");
$stmt_2->bindParam(1, $foo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt_2->execute();
$results_2 = $stmt_2->fetchAll();

$stmt_3 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE foo = :foo");
$stmt_3->bindParam("foo", $foo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt_3->execute();
$results_3 = $stmt_3->fetchAll();

print_r($results_1);
print_r($results_2);
print_r($results_3);
```

Answer (score 0):

`foo = ?` with parameter `"bar"` is equivalent to `foo = 'bar'`, not `foo = bar`.
I.e., you're selecting where the column equals a string, not another column.

There's no need to use a parameter here because `$foo` is not user input. (If it is, it should be validated against the finite set of columns in the table.)

---

Basically, there are two stages to executing an SQL query: parsing and evaluation. SQL injection can only happen when you expose the *parser* to user input. Evaluation is safe regardless of the values in the columns.

So when you run `WHERE foo = bar;`, it is parsed as "compare columns `foo` and `bar`". That's the only thing the database will do, regardless of what the values *in* those columns are.

Comment: I know, I meant foo = 'bar.'  This is a sample case; in the actual use, my variables are being set by values passed through $_POST, so I do need to use binding.  The last thing I want is to use the first case (which is the only one that gives me the results that I'm looking for).

I tried switching to:
$stmt_2 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo = ?");
$stmt_2->execute(array($foo));

which gives the same results.

The database driver is MySQL; I don't know off the top of my head what version, though I'll look it up if it matters.

Comment: Added some details to the answer. It seems that you just want the results of `$stmt_1` – in that case, it's fine as it is if the value of `$foo` doesn't come from user input. Whether the values in the column named by `$foo` (`bar`) come from user input doesn't matter (although when you INSERT them into the table, you _should_ use a parametrized query). I don't know why `$stmt_2` and `$stmt_3` give different result – they are equivalent. Can you try running each of them separately or in a different order?

Comment: `$foo` is coming from user input in a text field, so I have to protect against attacks.  Changing the order of `$stmt_2` and `$stmt_3` (or running them separately) doesn't change the result: `$stmt_2` is always an empty PDOStatement object, and `$stmt_3` always contains every entry in the table.